# verify password is correct before allowing user to change password

Tags: php

I am currently creating a page which will allow a user to change their password, but before they can do that I am getting them to enter their current password.

The php code is supposed to check that what they've entered matches the password in the database before then updating it to the new password, however this is not working and I'm just getting the password is incorrect message.

```
This is my page: 

<?php //include config

require_once('../../../includes/config.php');
$username =  $_SESSION['username'];

//if not logged in redirect to login page

if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: ../../login.php'); }

//If not got access redirect user

if($_SESSION['memberType'] == 1) { header('Location: ../../teacher/index.php'); }

if($_SESSION['memberType'] == 2) { header('Location: ../../student/index.php'); }

?>

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Admin - Edit User</title>

  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900;url=../../logout.php"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/normalise.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/learn.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/users.css">


</head>

<body>



<div class="sidenav">


<?php include('menu.php');?>

</div>

<div id="wrapper">


    <p><a href="users.php">Go Back</a></p>


    <h2>Edit User</h2>

<?php 


    //if form has been submitted process it

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


        //collect form data

        extract($_POST);


            if($currentPassword ==''){

                $error[] = 'Please enter the current password.';

            }

            if($password ==''){

                $error[] = 'Please enter the password.';

            }



            if($passwordConfirm ==''){

                $error[] = 'Please confirm the password.';

            }



            if($password != $passwordConfirm){

                $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';

            }

        if(!isset($error)){

            $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                     $checkPassword =  password_hash($currentPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                         if (password_verify ($oldPassword , $checkPassword)) { 

             if(isset($password)){

            $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

              try {            
                    //update into database

                    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = :username, password = :password WHERE memberID = :memberID') ;

                    $stmt->execute(array(

                        ':username' => $username,

                        ':password' => $hashedpassword,

                        ':memberID' => $memberID

                    ));



                //redirect to users page

                //header('Location: users.php?action=updated');

                //exit;

            }catch(PDOException $e) {

                echo $e->getMessage();                 

            }       
        }               

        } else {
           echo "password is incorrect";   
        }          

        }

        }



    //check for any errors

    if(isset($error)){

        foreach($error as $error){

            echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';

        }

    }



        try {



            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT memberID, username, password, memberType FROM users WHERE memberID = :memberID') ;

            $stmt->execute(array(':memberID' => $_GET['id']));

            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 



        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage();

        }



    ?>



    <form action='' method='post'>

        <input type='hidden' name='memberID' value='<?php echo $row['memberID'];?>'>

                 <input type='hidden' name='oldPassword' value='<?php echo $row['password'];?>'>     


        <p><label>Username</label><br />



        <input type='text' readonly name='username' value='<?php echo $row['username'];?>'></p>

        <p><label>Current Password</label><br />

        <input type='password' name='currentPassword' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['currentPassword'];}?>'></p>


        <p><label>Password (only to change)</label><br />

        <input type='password' name='password' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['password'];}?>'></p>



        <p><label>Confirm Password</label><br />

        <input type='password' name='passwordConfirm' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['passwordConfirm'];}?>'></p>



        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update User'></p>



    </form>



</div>



</body>

</html>
```

So my question would be, where have I gone wrong with this?

Comment: Are you fetching $oldPassword within one of the other included scripts?

Comment: Yes, when the page is loaded it's put into the form as a hidden field. Once the form is submitted it goes with the other values which is how I'm able to use it in the password_verify function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use password_verify I believe you need to pass in the plaintext password, in your case $currentPassword, instead of the hashed version.

Change this:

```
$checkPassword =  password_hash($currentPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if (password_verify ($oldPassword , $checkPassword)) {
```

To this:

```
if (password_verify($currentPassword, $oldPassword)) {
```

The docs state: `password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )`

Where `$password` is the plaintext password.

And `$hash` is the hash that was originally generated using `password_hash()`

Comment: that's exactly what was causing the issue, thank you!